# Como recuperar todos os dados de uma coluna datatable após uma busca feita?

Tags: jquery-datatables

Preciso recuperar os dados de uma coluna, mas quero somente os que estão visíveis na tela após digitar uma busca filtrando a quantidade de linhas.
Já conseguir recuperar uma coluna com todas as linhas da tabela assim:

```
var coluna = $('#tabela').DataTable().column().data();
console.log(coluna);
```

Mas preciso dos dados somente de algumas linhas que atendem a minha busca no campo "search" do datatables.
Tentei filtrar antes sem sucesso:

```
var palavra = $('div.dataTables_filter input').val(); //palavra buscada
var filtro = $('#tabela').DataTable().search(palavra).draw(); //filtrando as linhas que contem a palavra
var nomes = filtro.column().data(); //pegando os dados da coluna apos o filtro
console.log(nomes); //imprime os dados da coluna toda - todas as linhas da tabela
```

Agradeço desde já qualquer ajuda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar um `.each()` do jQuery e pegar os dados de uma determinada coluna da tabela:

```
var dados = [];
$('#tabela tbody tr').each(function(){
   dados.push(this.cells[0].textContent.trim());
});
```

Isso irá adicionar na array `dados[]` somente o texto de cada célula da primeira coluna da tabela (o índice `[0]` significa a primeira coluna).

Por exemplo, se você procurar pela letra "b" e a tabela mostrar:

```
-----------------------------
|   Nome        |   Idade   |
-----------------------------
|  Beatriz      |    25     |
-----------------------------
|  Bianca       |    21     |
-----------------------------
```

O resultado será `dados = ["Beatriz", "Bianca"]`.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Sam! Resolveu o meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Um comanndo no SQL que eu sei que funciona é o LIKE

```
SELECT nome_da_coluna FROM nome_da_tabela WHERE nome_da_coluna LIKE '%MINHA CHAVE DE BUSCA%'
```

Se seu script imprime o resultado em tempo real, então o resultado vai sendo impresso gradativamente assim que você escrever o M ... vai aparecer a fraze que esta na sua coluna, se você preencher MN, por exemplo, nao vai imprimir nada, se você colocar CHAVE vai aparecer a frase completa novamente... e por ai vai, espero ter te dado um norte.

Obs.: nao conselho usar * entre o SELECT e o FROM , tente sempre buscar a coluna que voce precisa.

Comment: Os dados vem de um banco com muitas pessoas. Eu não posso filtrar no SQL, preciso fazer na tela direto, por isso estou utilizando o Datatables (https://datatables.net/).